# A doubt in the proof of Burnside's formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

I read [a proof of Burnside's formula](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/homes-www/gelineau/devagreg/Formule_Burnside_Applications_Combinatoires.pdf) and I got stuck in a step.

> ### Burnside's formula
>
> Let $X$ be a finite set, and $G$ be a finite group acting on $X$.
>   Denote the $G$-orbits of $X$ as $X_1,\dots,X_k$, and
>   $\operatorname{Fix}_X(g) = \{x \in X \mid g \cdot x = x\}$.
>   Then
>   $$\bbox[yellow,5px,border:1px solid red]{k=\frac{1}{\lvert G \rvert} \sum\limits_{g \in G} \lvert\operatorname{Fix}_X(g)\rvert.}$$
>
> *Proof in the link:* Since $\operatorname{Fix}_X(g) = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k \operatorname{Fix}_{X_i}(g)$, one has $\lvert\operatorname{Fix}_X(g)\rvert = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \lvert\operatorname{Fix}_{X_i}(g) \rvert$.
>   \begin{align}
> k &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^k 1 \\
> & \stackrel{?}= \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{\lvert G \rvert} \sum\limits_{g \in G} \lvert\operatorname{Fix}_{X_i}(g) \rvert \tag{?}\label{?} \\
> &= \frac{1}{\lvert G \rvert} \sum\limits_{g \in G} \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \lvert\operatorname{Fix}_{X_i}(g) \rvert \\
> &= \frac{1}{\lvert G \rvert} \sum\limits_{g \in G} \lvert\operatorname{Fix}_{X}(g) \rvert
> \end{align}

I don't understand step \eqref{?}.  For each fixed $G$-orbit $X_i$, why is $\sum\limits_{g \in G} \lvert \operatorname{Fix}_{X_i}(g) \rvert = \lvert G \rvert$?

Thanks!

Comment: This is explained in the text: "Ainsi $1=Orb_X(G)|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}Fix_X(g)"$. Now apply it for each $X_i$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Got it !  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I should no long left this question unanswered since it's answered in the comments.  Therefore, I'll [post it as community wiki](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1149/290189) so that it no longer appears in the unanswered queue.

1. In the linked text, the case for $G$ acting transitively on $X$ is first proved, so that
   $$ \bbox[5px, border:1px solid black]{1=|\operatorname{Orb}_X(G)|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\operatorname{Fix}_X(g).} \tag1 \label1$$
2. Apply \eqref{1} to all $G$-orbits $X_i$.
   $$ 1=|\operatorname{Orb}_{X_i}(G)|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\operatorname{Fix}_{X_i}(g) \tag2 \label2$$
3. Sum \eqref{2} over $i = 1,\dots,k$ on both sides.
   $$ k=\sum_{i=1}^k |\operatorname{Orb}_{X_i}(G)|=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\operatorname{Fix}_{X_i}(g) \tag3 \label3$$